# Limit of $\frac{\sin(z)}z$ as $z \rightarrow \infty $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Hi I'm trying to solve

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(z)}{z}$$

where $z$ is a complex variable. I was told that the limit does not exist, so to show this I tried letting

$$\frac{\sin(z)}z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2iz}=\frac{e^x e^{iy}-e^x e^{-iy}}{i2x-2y}$$

and then I was thinking of letting $y=0$ and taking the limit in the $x$ direction and the same thing for $x=0$ but I run into trouble with this is this the right way to go about showing that the limit does not exist? Thank you for your help

Comment: Is $z$ a complex or a real variable? This small difference changes everything.

Comment: If $z$ is real, the limit exists and is $0$. If it is complex, then you have to consider the path you are taking the limit along.

Comment: complex i know in reals its 0

Comment: @SchrodingersCat : Is there a reason why you strongly prefer $\dfrac{(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})}{2iz}$ over $\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2iz}$? $\qquad$

Comment: I imagine you mean as $|z|\to\infty$. For $z$ real you know what happens. Now look at $z=-it$ where $t$ is large positive.

Comment: What do you mean by $z \to \infty$ if z is complex?

Comment: @kmitov Presumably $\lvert z\rvert \to\infty$, as André Nicolas wrote.

Comment: How can you let $z \to$ anything when $z$ is complex?

Comment: @Nima Bavari ? $z\to 6+89i$ is perfectly well defined, for instance.

Comment: @ClementC. I'm talking about cases such as $z \to \ell$ where $\ell$ is either real or $\pm \infty$. When you say $z \to \infty$ and $z = a + bi$ does one mean $a \to \infty$ or $b \to \infty$ or both? See, ill-defined.

Comment: $z\to \ell$ when $\ell$ is real is well-defined. $z\to \infty$ is indeed not, but this is what at least two comments above point out: the consensus is that the OP meant $\lvert z\rvert \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sequences: $(z_n)_n$ and $z^\prime_n)_n$ defined by $z_n = n$ and $z^\prime_n = in$, respectively.

Both $\lvert z_n\rvert,\lvert z^\prime_n\rvert \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$, yet
$$
\frac{\sin z_n}{z_n }\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
and
$$
\frac{\sin z^\prime_n}{z^\prime_n } = \frac{i\sinh n}{ in}=\frac{\sinh n}{ n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty
$$
as $\sinh x \operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^x}{2}$ (for $x\in\mathbb{R}$).